# deploy vuejs&laravel 5.8 project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, deployment

I'm a beginner in Vuejs , i've make a project and now i want to deploy it ,
i've tried to run

```
npm run build
```

like in Ember js and other js front end frameworks normally it will create a `dist` folder that contain my source code but i could not do that because the build script is not defined in the Vuejs which came with Laravel .
and i also tried to compress the project and upload it to my server and run it like other normal Laravel project but always Vuejs code not working, is there a specific way to deploy it ?? 
 i've tried to search but i didn't find the solution

Comment: Does it not compile or does the browser receive a 404 in the js console when loading your laravel page?

Comment: The scripts included in the default laravel installation can be seen in `package.json`. Try `npm run production`

Comment: No it don't display the 404 , the website works fine but without Vuejs handling

Comment: is your local app working, if not then add `id="app"` to your parent `div` and also ref the `app.js` like: `<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>`

Comment: In addition if your `npm run prod` works fine, then all the compiled and minified css and js reside in your public directory form where you can use them in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Your available scripts can be seen in `package.json` in the main laravel app folder.
There you should see something like:

```
"scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
```

Use `npm run production` for production builds and `npm run dev` for development builds.

In your `webpack.mix.js` file in the main folder, you can define your webpack configuration and therefore deployment settings. Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix for details.

If you leave the standard implementation, your `resources/js/app.js` will be compiled to `public/js/app.js`.
You can include the file in your Laravel Blade template like this:

`<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>`.

Comment: i've tried to run `npm run production` then i uploaded all files to the servers, but always the website work without Vuejs handling

Comment: That is not enough context to figure out what goes wrong. What happens if you open the console on that page and just type window.Vue? Does it exist?